# Checkout Error when confirming new order (MySQL server has gone away)

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout, sql, mysql-indexes

I am having some issues with my Magento site. I have 2 backend guys on it and they cant get to the bottom of it.

It started off with this error this morning

> Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away

When a customer has enters their delivery/payment details and clicks complete the order it  hangs for 1-2 minutes and then returns the above error.

We figured out that if a customer pays with paypal it goes through perfectly. Also with some credit card transactions, we noticed that some go through but we still get the above error.

We have increased
`max_allowed_packet` and `query_cache_size`

Any help would be greatly appreciated asIi am not a techie and my techies can't figure it out

Magento 1.9, Onestepcheckout

(`max_allowed_packet` is not the issue here)

Comment: Are you hosting your site on your own server, or do you have a hosting provider? Have you contacted whoemever is responsible for your server and asked them to check up on the MySQL server, and your website's connection to the MySQL server?

Comment: we host it on a shared cloud rackspace server - no i havent, the rest of the site works fine apart from that issue

Comment: Is the database running on the same 'server' as the website? i.e., the database connection is to 'localhost'? Also, which service level are you on with Rackspace - is there a chance they've 'secured' your site/server for you? I've seen them be a bit too aggressive with that at times.

Comment: its on a different 'server'. we are on min service level which is no use at all. they havent touched anything on the site

Comment: Tried ping between server and database:
8 packets transmitted, 8 received, 0% packet loss, time 7168ms

Comment: Ask them to restart the MySQL server, or have one of your guys restart it, just to rule that out. However, based on the other info you're reporting, it's starting to sound like there's a problem with specific database tables or queries - the error only appears at checkout and only with payment methods other than PayPal. Not sure if you have phpmyadmin setup or not, but if you do, check to see if any tables need to be repaired or optimized.

Answer (score 2):

This could be a few different causes:

- MySQL server could be configured with a low wait_timeout setting - this would be odd though, because you're saying this happens within 1-2 minutes, and the default for wait_timeout is generally in hours, not minutes.
- Magento is sending too large of a packet or query - but you've increased max_allowed_packet, so that's unlikely. It would also be odd to have an order exceed max_allowed_packet.
- There is a networking (packet loss, firewall, etc) issue between your website and the MySQL database server. That usually only crops up on shared hosting (overloaded/oversubscribed or incorrectly configured database server on a different machine than your account) or on elaborate cluster configurations with multiple servers.

Comment: in 2.5 years i have never seen this issue. thats why i find it weird. As i said if paypal is selected it works fine. We have tried doing a $0 transaction with no credit card required and it crashes also

Comment: Do you have a one step checkout extension installed? Do your products have a lot of options the user selects from? Are you seeing any issues with your indexers (in your Magento admin panel, check System -> Index Management). Basically - it sounds like you have a database issue that's cropped up suddenly, but if you haven't changed anything on the site, there has to be another cause. It could be that a specific table has crashed, or grown too large, or that Rackspace did change something (i.e., upgraded MySQL versions, etc).

Comment: yep we use onestepcheckout. We have about 7 options each. Check them out at funkychritmasjumpers.co.uk regarding indexes nothing unusual. But we did have an issue last week where all the configurable products lost association with their child products. IT was after we deleted a store on the server. There was an issue with it. but it was sorted.

Comment: It sounds more likely that the query is being killed by another query. This can happen if a reindex is started in the admin (even a product save if indexes are on auto), when an order is being placed. Change all your indexes to manual, apart from stock and price, then remove access to the index management page using admin ACLs and see if your issue persists.